# Counting words after grouping records (Part 2)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Although I am [having an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925959/826983) for what I want to achieve, the problem is that it's way to slow. The data set is not very large. It's 50GB in total but the affected part is probably just between 5 to 10GB of data. However, the following is what I require, but it's way to slow And by slow I mean it was running for an hour and it didn't terminate.

```py
df_ = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1', 'hello how are are you today'),
    ('1', 'hello how are you'),
    ('2', 'hello are you here'),
    ('2', 'how is it'),
    ('3', 'hello how are you'),
    ('3', 'hello how are you'),
    ('4', 'hello how is it you today')
], schema=['label', 'text'])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='text', outputCol='tokens')
tokens = tokenizer.transform(df_)

token_counts.groupby('label')\
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col('token'), F.col('count'))).alias('text'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Which gives me the token count for each label:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|text                                                            |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|3    |[[are,2], [how,2], [hello,2], [you,2]]                          |
|1    |[[today,1], [how,2], [are,3], [you,2], [hello,2]]               |
|4    |[[hello,1], [how,1], [is,1], [today,1], [you,1], [it,1]]        |
|2    |[[hello,1], [are,1], [you,1], [here,1], [is,1], [how,1], [it,1]]|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I think the call to `explode()` is way too expensive for this.

I don't know but it might be faster to count the tokens in each "dokument" and later merge it in a `groupBy()`:

```py
df_.select(['label'] + [udf_get_tokens(F.col('text')).alias('text')])\
    .rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(Counter(x[1]).items()))) \
    .toDF(schema=['label', 'text'])\
    .show()
```

Gives the counts:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|label|                text|
+-----+--------------------+
|    1|[[are,2], [hello,...|
|    1|[[are,1], [hello,...|
|    2|[[are,1], [hello,...|
|    2|[[how,1], [it,1],...|
|    3|[[are,1], [hello,...|
|    3|[[are,1], [hello,...|
|    4|[[you,1], [today,...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Is there a way to merge those token counts in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If groups defined by `id` are largish the obvious target for improvement is shuffle size. Instead of shuffling text, shuffle labels. First vectorize input

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

pipeline_model = Pipeline(stages=[
    Tokenizer(inputCol='text', outputCol='tokens'),
    CountVectorizer(inputCol='tokens', outputCol='vectors')
]).fit(df_)

df_vec = pipeline_model.transform(df_).select("label", "vectors")
```

Then aggregate:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector
from collections import defaultdict

def seq_func(acc, v):
    if isinstance(v, SparseVector):
        for i in v.indices:
            acc[int(i)] += v[int(i)]
    if isinstance(v, DenseVector): 
        for i in len(v):
            acc[int(i)] += v[int(i)]
    return acc

def comb_func(acc1, acc2):
    for k, v in acc2.items():
        acc1[k] += v
    return acc1

aggregated = rdd.aggregateByKey(defaultdict(int), seq_func, comb_func)
```

And map back to the required output:

```py
vocabulary = pipeline_model.stages[-1].vocabulary

def f(x, vocabulary=vocabulary):
    # For list of tuples use  [(vocabulary[i], float(v)) for i, v in x.items()]
    return {vocabulary[i]: float(v) for i, v in x.items()}


aggregated.mapValues(f).toDF(["id", "text"]).show(truncate=False)
# +---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |id |text                                                                                 |
# +---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |4  |[how -> 1.0, today -> 1.0, is -> 1.0, it -> 1.0, hello -> 1.0, you -> 1.0]           |
# |3  |[how -> 2.0, hello -> 2.0, are -> 2.0, you -> 2.0]                                   |
# |1  |[how -> 2.0, hello -> 2.0, are -> 3.0, you -> 2.0, today -> 1.0]                     |
# |2  |[here -> 1.0, how -> 1.0, are -> 1.0, is -> 1.0, it -> 1.0, hello -> 1.0, you -> 1.0]|
# +---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This worth trying only if text part is considerably large - otherwise all required transformations between `DataFrame` and Python objects might be more expensive than `collecting_list`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for providing an answer! Unfortunately I can test it only next week on Tuesday but I won't forget to accept it :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response - didn't got time until today to continue working on this. Your answer words perfectly and definitely faster than the `explode()` version! Thank you!